# notify_all_at_thread_exit doesn't exist in Cygwin GCC

Tags: multithreading, c++11, cygwin, condition-variable

When I try to build the following simple test program in 32-bit Cygwin with GCC version 4.9.2, I get an error saying:

```
error: ‘notify_all_at_thread_exit’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

This makes me think that this specific method hasn't been ported to Cygwin. Does anyone know if I am either doing something wrong or if I can determine that this indeed is missing from Cygwin?

Build line:

```
 /usr/bin/c++.exe -std=gnu++11 -o NotifyAllAtThreadExitTest.cc.o -c NotifyAllAtThreadExitTest.cc
```

Code snippet:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;

bool ready = false;

void thread_func()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    ready = true;
    std::notify_all_at_thread_exit(cv, std::move(lk));
}

int test()
{
    std::thread t(thread_func);
    t.detach();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    while(!ready) {
        cv.wait(lk);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Same error compiling on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69bf33d2e62e15d3), which I believe is a Linux environment. It would appear that the problem is not Cygwin-specific, but libstdc++ itself is missing `notify_all_at_thread_exit` in 4.9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 4.9 release series, libstdc++ does not implement [`std::notify_all_at_thread_exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/notify_all_at_thread_exit). It will be present in the gcc 5.0 release, in fact [it was just added in revision 218255 on 2014-12-02](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=218255).

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. Thanks Casey!